# Geoserver url is not working

Tags: geoserver

I'm using GeoServer since couple of months and it were working fine. Today, after some gap, when I typed localhost:8080/geoserver; it is giving an error

Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

localhost
20/12/2013 5:51:07 PM
Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8o PHP/5.3.4 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1

Comment: Are you sure GeoServer is actually running? The error looks like it's coming from the servlet container.

Comment: @GIS-Jonathan... Yeah, GeoServer is actully running. I'm also thinking same, it seems it is coming from sevlet container. The GeoServer is in Xampp, Apache Tomcat. And The xampp is actully running absolutely fine, the phpmyAdmin is also working fine. But something went wrong with this Geoserver :(

Comment: Does the geoserver.log file contain anything to indicate it received the request? That'll at least indicate where the problem is.

Comment: @GIS-Jonathan...Yeah, geoserver.log file contains the information of last time it receives the request i.e. 2013-03-12 09:07:05,981 INFO [geoserver.wms] -

Comment: If that's your last log entry, then that's March! The issue is definitely with your servlet container then.

Comment: @GIS-Jonathan... No, its 3rd of December. By the way, what do you suggest, any possible suggestion?

Comment: This should be an ISO formatted date - thus it should be 12th March. But no, I'm afraid I have no solutions. Maybe try installing a completely clean GeoServer in there and see what happens.

Comment: Is Tomcat running?

Comment: @neogeomat... The startup.bat is running. It gives "Server startup in ... ms".
PhpMyAdmin is working fine, all the files with in htdocs folder are working fine.